# FourierParameters causing function not to simplify

Tags: simplifying-expressions, fourier-analysis, integral-transforms

When evaluating this expression, *Mathematica* simplifies the result:

```
FourierTransform[FourierTransform[u[t], t, s], s, t]
```

This simplifies to `u[-t]`, as expected.

But let's say I want this expression using different Fourier parameters.

```
FourierTransform[
  FourierTransform[u[t], t, s, FourierParameters -> {1, - 1}],
  s, t, FourierParameters -> {1, -1}
] // FullSimplify
```

When evaluating this, *Mathematica* leaves the result unaltered, with or without `FullSimplify`. The result should be $2\pi\ u(-t)$. Is it possible to get this result, or a similar result using these parameters? I would like to test these kinds of expressions with *Mathematica*, but without the right parameters it is kind of useless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest reporting the unevaluated `FourierTransform[]` with explicitly-set `FourierParameters` to support.

In the meantime, you can do this instead:

```
SetOptions[FourierTransform, FourierParameters -> {1, -1}];
FourierTransform[FourierTransform[u[t], t, s], s, t]
   2 π u[-t]
```

Comment: I sent a report with this problem. The suggested fix is actually what I want since it saves you from typing `FourierParameters -> ...` over and over. I have never heard of `SetOptions` but it seems a really useful function.